# chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived uses a tabId that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I'm trying to detect HTTP headers and change some values but sometimes, in the callback function `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(data){...}, ...)` `data.tabId` contains the value of a tab that doesn't even exist.

For example, if I'm receiving http responses and I'm in tab with id 5, sometimes I receive some responses from a tab with id 6 which doesn't exist. Why is that?

Comment: It's probably a hidden prerendered tab for web search performed when you type in the address bar.